# WPF DataGrid DatePicker Format issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datepicker

I allow a user to pick a date inside a DataGrid datepicker like

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"></    DatePicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

So if a user picks

03/04/2014 - fine, the date will go into the database as 2014-03-04 00:00:00.000

However there is an issue with the format and in the US style, I think, as if a user chooses

13/04/2014

The DatePicker will come up with an error - a red box will appear (this is not due to my vaildation) And the user will not be able to save to the database.

I know its because the month is first, the day is second and the year third (mm/dd/yyyy)

Is there a way I could use the datepicker in the UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) which should solve the problem?

Thanks